# How to properly add the package "ConditionalJuMP" in Julia language?

Tags: package, julia, julia-jump

The command `"Pkg.add("ConditionalJuMP)"` works.

However when, I am trying the command (`using ConditionalJuMP`), I am getting this error. Anyone can propose me something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at `ConditionalJuMP`'s GitHub repo? The [latest release (0.1.0)](https://github.com/rdeits/ConditionalJuMP.jl/releases) has been for Julia 1.0, and thus seems pretty outdated by now with not much work going on...

Diff `master` w.r.t. 0.1.0 release: [here](https://github.com/rdeits/ConditionalJuMP.jl/releases)

Telling from your screenshot, Julia tried to precompile `ConditionalJuMP` into `./julia/compiled/v1.5`. So I guess you are using Julia 1.5, right?

First thing I'd do is trying to go back to Julia 1.0 and see whether `ConditionalJuMP` would be working with it (or if that woudlnd't suffice on its own by actively chossing earlier `JuMP` versions as explicit packages within your project), since overall it seems like `GenericRangeConstraint` is missing/not found - which was part of earlier `JuMP` versions, but probably isn't anymore (not a `JuMP` expert here, though).

Comment: That's right, I'm using the latest Julia version 1.5. I will try using Julia 1.0 then and I will inform you if this works. Thank you in any case!

Comment: For the record, generally this kind of thing shouldn't happen. Modern packages should have a `Project.toml` file rather than a `REQUIRE` file, and in the `Project.toml` file there should be a `[compat]` section that specifies compatibility requirements. When that system works well (and increasingly, it does), installing `ConditionalJuMP` would have automatically also installed an old version of `JuMP` and would use that.

Answer (score 0):

ConditionalJuMP doesn't support the latest version of JuMP. You will need to install an old version via: `] add JuMP@0.18`.

I would encourage you to instead use the latest version of JuMP, and its native support for indicator constraints: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/constraints/#Indicator-constraints-1